# Eclipse formatter: conditional expression on same indentation level

Tags: java, eclipse, indentation

My conditional expression is currently formatted as follows:

```
class Example extends AnotherClass {

    int Example(boolean Argument) {
        return argument
            ? 100000
                : 200000;
    }
}
```

is there a way to format it in such a way that the `:` is on the same indentation level a the question mark:

```
class Example extends AnotherClass {

    int Example(boolean Argument) {
        return argument
            ? 100000
            : 200000;
    }
}
```

or is this impossible with the current Eclipse version (Oxygen)?

The sample code was copied from the formatter in Eclipse, obviously my lines are a bit longer than that.

---

Bonus: If it is currently possible then in which version of the Eclipse JDT did it become possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can achieve this but setting the options like described in the following image : [image]

The important options are :

- the `Indent on column` on Indentation policy (last droplist)
- the `Wrap all elements, indent all but the first element` in the Line wrapping policy

Of course after selecting the Expressions=>Conditionals submenu.

Comment: Hmm, my older Eclipse version shows different output with these exact same settings, trying Oxygen now...

Comment: OK, so that reacts differently. Any reason why the column starts somewhere at the end of the line? Did you yourself add an enter in there?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I use Oxygen, and no, I didn't change anything to the original text